# Print job stuck on spooling with SYSTEM as an Owner

Tags: printing, print-spooler, print-server

We have a new machine running Windows Server 2016, with a lot of printers.
Three of them seems to get stuck when a user tries to print .jpg files.

When this happens if I check the Print Job Queue, I see that there two print jobs, one with the original user name as an Owner with status Printing, and another one with the same name, with SYSTEM as an Owner with Spooling status and nothing happens. The print job is not released, and any other print job cannot be printed (we have set the printers to finish spooling). I cannot delete the jobs. In order to clear this "error" we restart the print spooler.

Extra details:
Somehow the print job name is also changed, and it gets some weird string before the Document name. For example "R:5976Vz:**'original document-name'**.jpg". The string before the document name is random.

[Here is a snip-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byxrz.png)

Other users can print with no problems. The same users that have this problem, can print other type of documents with no problems. I see that this happens only with .jpg files.

Any ideas ? Did someone else had this issue before ?

I've checked the drivers and they are ok; I've checked the logs, but the Operational logs are empty.

Best regards,
Marius

Comment: I've removed the printers from the server, and I've added them again, and I've also reinstalled the driver (they had the same driver). For now it seems to work.

PS. There were also other printers using the same driver, and they worked, so I excluded the driver to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the root cause of this, but it seems to work now, after doing the following actions:

1. I've removed the driver
2. Delete the printers
3. Install the printers again, and also installing the driver again

Since I've re-installed the printers, we've not met with this situation again.

---

Later edit:
I found where the error came from and how to reproduce it. Just print something from Edge browser or Microsoft Photos.
We use a print management software called PaperCut. Here is the full explanation:
https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/Windows10Printing#GroupPolicy

With the release of Windows 10, there has been an increase in customers using Windows 10 Applications for their printing needs. This includes the Edge browser. Windows 10 Applications are those which can be obtained from the Windows Store.

Popular Windows 10 Applications which support printing include Microsoft Reader, Edge browser, OneNote, Maps, and Photos.

When the print driver in use is Type 3, the spool file generated from these applications contains a special XPS2GDI tag. These spool file types are processed two times by the Print Spooler service. The first pass by the Print Spooler will generate a new spool file in the Page Description Language the printer understands. The Print Spooler service will send this second spool file to the device.

When FindMe printing is configured, and the non default Server Side Rendering is encountered, the double spool file creation will occur on the release printer as shown in the screenshot below. In the case where the print jobs are still rendering on the server, one can see two print jobs for the single job sent in the release printer.
Anyways, since I've reinstalled the printers, I did not have any issue.