# Windows photos jamming print queue

Tags: printing, windows-photo-viewer, print-spooler

Whenever any of our users prints an image from the windows 10 photo app or a pdf from chrome or edge it is causing the print spooler queue to jam.  That print will stay in the queue till it's turn, then get to 99.9% of processing and just hang there and never complete.  I have to manually stop the spooler service, delete the job and restart the service.

This is a Develop ineo+ 458 printer running off Windows server 2012 R2 deployed through GP.  My group policy forces client side rendering, as does my settings in printer management.

I suspect my issue is similar to this, but I don't use any 3rd party printer management apps.
[Print job stuck on spooling with SYSTEM as an Owner](https://superuser.com/questions/1470763/print-job-stuck-on-spooling-with-system-as-an-owner/1473140#1473140)

To get around this, I've set the machines to use the old (and infinitely better) windows image viewer and adobe pfd reader to be the defaults, but every now and then something goes wrong and things get reset.

Comment: "windows image viewer and adobe pfd reader to be the defaults" resolving the issue points to a software interaction (or the interface between software and driver).  Maybe poke around to see if the older software uses a different method (i.e. the way WIA replaced TWAIN for scanners) or the new method fails to send the "all clear," or Bi-directional communication is failing

Comment: Also, there have been some major security vulnerabilities patched recently for print spooler